# Flexbox not working in buttons in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

Apparently Firefox doesn't like `display: flex` on buttons. Is there a way to t correct this?

CSS:

```
button {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

    button div:first-child {
        -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
        -webkit-order: 2;
        -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
        -ms-flex-order: 2;
        order: 2;
    }

    button div:last-child {
        -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
        -webkit-order: 1;
        -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
        -ms-flex-order: 1;
        order: 1;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<button>
    <div>
        <p>First</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Second</p>
    </div>
</button>
```

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/ziwadabo/2

Answer (score 32, accepted):

tl;dr: Just put a div inside of your `<button>`, and make *that* div `display:flex`.

See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=984869#c2 for why `display` doesn't do what you expect on `<button>` in Firefox (and for similar things that don't work in Firefox or Webkit/Blink, for similar reasons).

Here's your modified jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ziwadabo/4/

Comment: Interesting, I guess that makes sense. Dumb system-level elements, always screwing things up. Thanks!

Comment: phrasing content (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content) is not allowed in buttons. see this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: @jbergloff, how is that relevant to this thread? What piece of phrasing content was someone suggesting be put in a button here?

Comment: A `<div>` inside a `<button>` would not pass W3C validation (you'll get a `Element div not allowed as child of element button in this context` error). But you can use `<span>` instead.